# Passing Event handler as parameter

Tags: c#, events

Okay I don't really know what's wrong with my code and What's going on so

`class Activity` has the following methods

```
protected struct EventParams
    {
        public object sender;
        public EventArgs e;
    }
private EventParams WaitEventRaise_Body(ref EventHandler<EventArgs> handler, int timeout)
    {
        AutoResetEvent receiver = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        EventParams result = new EventParams();

        EventHandler<EventArgs> handle = new EventHandler<EventArgs>((sender, e) =>
        {
            result.e = e;
            result.sender = sender;
            receiver.Set();
        });

        handler += handle;

        if (timeout > 0)
        {
            receiver.WaitOne(timeout);
        }
        else
        {
            receiver.WaitOne();
        }

        return result;
    }

protected EventParams WaitEventRaise(ref EventHandler<EventArgs> handler)
{
    return WaitEventRaise_Body(ref handler, -1);
}
protected EventParams WaitEventRaise(ref EventHandler<EventArgs> handler, int timeout)
{
    return WaitEventRaise_Body(ref handler, timeout);
}
```

Okay so I find myself writing over and over again the AutoResetEvent thing so I decided to create a method. But when I try to call this method from derived class `Bot : Activity`

```
EventParams eventResult = WaitEventRaise(ref currentJob.JobReported);
```

gives

> Error 30  The best overloaded method match for
>   Project.Activity.WaitEventRaise(ref
>   System.EventHandler)' has some invalid arguments

currentJob is a `Job : Activity` class that has the event

```
public event EventHandler<JobReport> JobReported;
```

and

```
class JobReport : EventArgs
```

What I want to do is there is a bot thing does jobs, actually it creates jobs and waits them for finish their work. Job class raises event inside to make bot class noticed that it finished its work. And bot class waits until job raises event. So I hope its clear. And I'm sorry that english is not my native language.

Comment: `EventHandler<JobReport>` can't be inferred as `EventHandler<EventArgs>` so this won't work.

Comment: doesnt this work for JobReport?
class JobReport : EventArgs

Comment: OK I tried to
 
EventParams eventResult = WaitEventRaise(ref currentJob.test);

where

public event EventHandler<EventArgs> test;

and it gives me the error: The event test can only appear on the left hand side of += etc. etc.

Comment: the main issue is you can't pass a *reference* to an event handler you can only pass a copy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, you can't refer to an event like that. Two options:

- Pass in delegates for "adding a handler" and "removing a handler":

  ```
  EventParams eventResult = 
      WaitEventRaise<JobReport>(handler => currentJob.JobReported += handler,
                                handler => currentJob.JobReported -= handler);
  ```

  where `WaitEventRaise` would be declared as:

  ```
  EventParams WaitEventRaise<T>(Action<EventHandler<T>> add,
                                Action<EventHandler<T>> remove)
                               where T : EventArgs
  ```
- Pass in the `EventInfo` corresponding to the event, which you'd fetch with reflection

Neither of these is terribly pleasant - it's a problem that Rx comes up against as well.

Comment: But isn't there is a short solution I mean I have to write these things over and over again. Isn't there is a solution that I just pass what I have to work on and receive the result? Just single method I mean

Comment: @user1046403: No. Basically events themselves aren't first class entities in C# (nor are properties, or constructors... methods sort of are via method group conversions).

Comment: @user1046403: Please don't add meaningless comments just to attract attention. As it happens, I was already replying to your comment - but in the future, I would explicitly *not* reply if I feel you're trying to badger me like this. It's not like this is the only thing I'm doing.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying to figure out how to actually invoke the add and remove actions. According to the signature they require a parameter of type EventHandler<T> passed during the invocation.

Comment: @pnizzle: I'm afraid I don't follow you. I suggest you ask a new question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what's `Job` class contains or what `currentJob.JobReported` is, but judging from the error `WaitEventRaise` method needs `System.EventHandler` which is a method like

```
private void MeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```